# how add gradle into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have include buildship in Eclipse from marketplace from:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration

And got the gradle-bin from:

https://gradle.org/gradle-download/ and set the path variable.

But when trying to create Gradle project in Eclipse, Eclipse is trying to download `gradle-2.14-bin.zip` (unable to download due to slow internet connection) which I already have.

Please tell how add Gradle in Eclipse.

Comment: I believe Eclipse Neon (just released) includes Gradle, so no need to get it from the Marketplace if you have that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while creating Gradle project in eclipse , after giving name click next and in Gradle distribution browse local directory where you have install/extract gradle binaries.

[image]

Comment: You could also use the "recommended" Gradle wrapper